# Angular 7. Don't check a validation in a reactive form the first time

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

In Angular 7, I have the following code:

```
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      name: ['', [Validators.required], this.validateSomething.bind(this)],
    });
```

then I do some things and finally I initialize the values with an object `myObject` that I obtain from my DB and I know it does not break any validation:

```
    this.formGroup.setValue({
      id: myObject.id,
      name: myObject.name
    }, {
      emitEvent: false
    });
```

My `validateSomething` is quite complex and I would like that, in my initial `setValue` it didn't run to save some computations.

I found the function `setValidators()` and I thought I could do something like:

- First:

```
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      id: [],
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
    });
```

- then:

```
    this.formGroup.setValue({
      id: myObject.id,
      name: myObject.name
    }, {
      emitEvent: false
    });
```

- And just afterwards:

```
this.formGroup.controls.name.setValidator(validateSomething.bind(this));
```

But it doesn't work. The validation simply does not work anymore.

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: You could create your FormGroup right afer you got your data. Also you could use `validateOn: 'blur'` otherwise if you validate regular input where user types then after each keypress the input is re-validated and thus your 1 validation check is insignificant

Comment: In `validateSomething` you could check if the field is `touched` and / or `dirty` before validate. Something like `this.myForm.get('name').touched && this.myForm.get('name').dirty`.

Comment: Have you made measurements and proven that calling this validator initially (which will later be called every time you enter something into the input field) causes a noticeable performance problem? If not, than don't try to be smart and increase the complexity of the code to solve a non-existent problem. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Sergey: that would be a good option but it's not possible in my case...

Comment: @JBNizet: The validation does not cause performance problems yet but it calls the DB and we have a bottleneck there. You are totally right and it is probably not worth to do it, but the answer from riorudo was so simple that I could apply it easily without creating much noise.

Comment: @riorudo: if you create the answer I'll accept it. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your validation method `validateSomething` you could check if the field is `touched` and / or `dirty` before validate.

Something like:

`this.myForm.get('name').touched && this.myForm.get('name').dirty`.